# Fill in missing values in Pandas Dataframe wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose 'df' is dataframe object, 'ca' is one of the variables.

```
>>> df.ca.value_counts()
0.0    176
1.0     65
2.0     38
3.0     20
?        4
Name: ca, dtype: int64
```

As you can see, I have four missing values. I want to fill in them. Using below code:

```
>>> df.loc[df.ca == '?', 'ca'] = 0.0
0.0    176
1.0     65
2.0     38
3.0     20
0.0      4
Name: ca, dtype: int64
```

Why I got 5 unique values? I want to merge fifth row into first row, i.e.

```
0.0   176 + 4 = 180
1.0     65
2.0     38
3.0     20
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `'?'` was one of your values, I know that `df.ca` is either `dtype` `object` or `string`.  When you `replace('?', 0.)` you now have both string `'0.0'` and float `0.0`.  After you convert all to float, you shouldn't have a problem.

```
df.ca.replace('?', 0.).astype(float).value_counts()

0.0    180
1.0     65
2.0     38
3.0     20
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pretty much works too:

```
In [193]: df = pd.DataFrame({'ca': [0.0]*176 + [1.0]*65 + [2.0]*38 + [3.0]*20 + ['?']*4})

In [194]: df.ca.value_counts()
Out[194]: 
0.0    176
1.0     65
2.0     38
3.0     20
?        4
Name: ca, dtype: int64

In [195]: df.loc[df.ca == '?', 'ca'] = 0.0

In [196]: df.ca.value_counts()
Out[196]: 
0.0    180
1.0     65
2.0     38
3.0     20
Name: ca, dtype: int64
```